# Make entire background of radio button clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am trying to create this exact same thing using radio buttons
http://codepen.io/Athulks/pen/EZGpjZ .

So far I have reached this much

```css
.display_radio input[type="radio"] {
    background-color: #fed55c;
    border: 2px solid #fffdf6;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    padding: 9px;
    margin: 36px 0 0 13px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.money-radio-container span {
    margin: 35px 2px 0px 7px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
}
.display_radio {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fed55c;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fed55c;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 money-radio-container">
    <div class="display_radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="10"><span>$ 10 </span>
    </div>
    <div class="display_radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="20"><span>$ 20 </span>
    </div>
    <div class="display_radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="50"><span>$ 50 </span>
    </div>
    <div class="display_radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="100"><span>$ 100 </span>
    </div>
    <div class="display_radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="150"><span>$ 150 </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the entire div clickable and remove that radio icon from the middle of div. So that It looks exactly as in the first demo i made with buttons?

Comment: Put it in a `<label></label>` tag instead of the `<div></div>`. That is literally the function of that tag.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen label instead of radio button or Div ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.display_radio input[type="radio"] {
    background-color: #fed55c;
    border: 2px solid #fffdf6;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    padding: 9px;
    margin: 36px 0 0 13px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.money-radio-container span {
    margin: 35px 2px 0px 7px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
}
.display_radio {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fed55c;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fed55c;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 money-radio-container">
    <label class="display_radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="10"><span>$ 10 </span>
    </label>
    <label class="display_radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="20"><span>$ 20 </span>
    </label >
    <label class="display_radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="50"><span>$ 50 </span>
    </label >
    <label class="display_radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="100"><span>$ 100 </span>
    </label >
    <label class="display_radio">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="150"><span>$ 150 </span>
    </label >
</div>
```

Comment: I want to hide the radiobutton "round" too..is there anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use label tag instead of the button

```
<div class="display_radio">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="optradio" class="money-radio" value="10">
    <label for="radio1" class="btn btn-radiotype btn-circle" >$5</label>
</div>
```

then you can give 'money-radio' class, display:none, so that the radio button won't be visible but it'll still work as it should. The values will still be stored in the respective radio buttons.

```
.money-radio {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you can try sonething like;

`<a href='mypage'><div class="col-md-12 money-radio-container"></a>`